# Does the Touch of Gracelessness spell require an attack roll?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, touch-attacks

I've noticed that the Touch of Gracelessness spell doesn't mention a needing to make a touch attack, but it does say you touch the enemy. Does that mean you need to succeed on the touch attack, and then the enemy needs to fail the Fortitude save?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 5):

The spell [*touch of gracelessness*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-gracelessness/) has the entry *Range: Touch*. This [Range](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Range) means that "[y]ou must touch a creature… to affect it" with the *touch of gracelessness* spell. This Range entry also means that the rules on *both* how to make [touch attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#Touch_Attacks) *and* how to employ [touch spells in combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#Touch_Spells_in_Combat) apply.

Despite the spell's description *not* saying that it requires a touch *attack*, when in combat a caster must make a touch attack to touch an enemy or a creature that's otherwise avoiding the caster's touch. Nothing special exempts the spell *touch of gracelessness* from the normal rules.

---

***Note:*** Other questions and answers address the horribly under-detailed [accidental discharge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=accidental%20discharge%20%5Bpathfinder-1e%5D) rules ("If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges"). And another question's answers describe [how to detect a touch spell's held charge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84391/8610).

Comment: Note that, as a corollary to your second sentence, you *don't* ordinarily have to make a touch attack when casting a touch-range spell on an ally-- "You can touch up to 6 willing targets as part of the casting, but all targets of the spell must be touched in the same round that you finish casting the spell. "